# Write to S3 in Parquet format in Python (or Typescript) without spark

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, parquet

I want to write data to S3 in Parquet format from inside AWS Lambda job, without using Spark. Either Python or Typescript should work. If the function cane to append to the existing Parquet file that would be even more awesome. Thank you!

Comment: S3 is not a file system. There is no "append"; there is no "rename". there is only create Green

Comment: Ok, how do I write it all at once?

Comment: sorry, i only work through the spark/hive etc and the s3a connector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use PyArrow library or the AWS SDK for JavaScript in Typescript to write down data to S3 in Parquet format from inside an Lambda function.

Comment: Does this sound like the correct approach? https://janakiev.com/blog/pandas-pyarrow-parquet-s3/
I didn't see a way to specify the schema when writing. I though it is supposed to be specified when creating the parquet file.

Comment: Is there a way to append new data which has the same schema?

Comment: Couldn't find any mention of parquet in AWS SDK, would really appreciate some points here.

Comment: Check out repository [S3 pyArrow ] (https://github.com/RobinaMirbahar/Google-Cloud-Solutions/blob/main/S3%20in%20Parquet%20format%20in%20Python%20(or%20Typescript).py)

Comment: Robina, this is awesome. Really appreciate!